# Битрикс. ЧПУ в умном фильтре

Tags: битрикс, чпу

Как можно сделать подобный каталог товаров как на этом сайте http://rus-buket.ru/catalog т.е чтобы умный фильтр формировал ЧПУ ссылки без параметров? Подскажите или направьте в нужную сторону, как на Битриксе можно реализовать подобный функционал? Фильтр с ЧПУ.

Comment: Похоже на псевдо фильтр. Множество категорий которые оформлены в виде фильтра. Заголовок прописывается каждый раз новый.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле реализовать такое не сложно.

В примере есть 5 параметров, которые в URI занимают своё место.

В urlrewrite нам нужно создать новое правило — что бы из `/catalog/filter-(.*)` отправлял данные например в файл `/catalog/filter.php`. В этом файле вы делаете проверку URL и с помощью `catalog.section` и параметра `arrFilter` делаете фильтрацию.

Свойства храните в HL для того что бы их удобнее было выводить и фильтровать по ним.

Но лучше если Вы доработаете комплексный компонент `catalog`. [Как это сделать](http://academy.1c-bitrix.ru/education/index.php?COURSE_ID=66&LESSON_ID=5890&LESSON_PATH=5863.5890)

Если же Вам нужно в каком то разделе фильтровать, то можно включить фильтр в режим ЧПУ и указать в настройках ЧПУ фильтра к примеру `#SECTION_ID#/filter-#SMART_FILTER_PATH#` тогда в результатах фильтра по свойству CMS и значению свойства битрикс мы получим url `/catalog/filter-cms-is-bitrix`.

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: да, с чпу разобрался, еще вопрос не подскажите а можно ли как то манипулировать мета данными  в зависимости от выбранного фильтра ?